# Bash: grabbing the second line and last line of output (ls -lrS) only

Tags: bash, shell, awk, ls

I am looking to get the second line and last line of what the ls -lrS command outputs. Ive been using `ls -lrS | (head -2 | tail -1) && (tail -n1)` But it seems to only get the first line only, and I have to press control C to stop it.

Another problem I am having is using the awk command, I wanted to just grab the file size and file name. If I were to get the correct lines (second and last) my desired output would be

```
files=$(ls -lrS | (head -2 | tail -1) && (tail -n1) awk '{ print "%s", $5; "%s", $8; }' )
```

I was hoping it would print:

1234 file.abc

12345 file2.abc

Comment: Don't parse `ls`'s output. Use `stat` command

Comment: So you want the size and name of the smallest and largest sized entries in the given directory?

Comment: If you want to copy the same content to two places for separate processing, you need to tee it. Regular pipes don't do that.

Comment: Also, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for discussion of why parsing output of `ls` is unreliable. If you have GNU `find`, it would be the better tool for this job (with `-printf`).

Comment: @bishop Yes that is correct

Comment: I also don't fully understand how awk works... I'm new to shell scripting

Comment: Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins. Do not buy any other awk book as the rest are outdated at best.

Comment: What do you want the output to be if `ls` only outputs 1 line? What about 2 lines?

Comment: @Lenny, awk isn't really a subset of "shell scripting" -- it's a whole, independent (and very useful!) programming language in its own right, but it isn't part of POSIX sh, and thus isn't itself a shell language.

Comment: (For anyone curious: Ed and I had an extended discussion on what is and isn't part of "POSIX sh" in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96578/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-ed-morton; to sumarize: even though it's not a shell component as such, `awk` is very much guaranteed to be part of/present on/available in a compliant POSIX system).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
ls -lrS | awk 'NR==2 { print; } END { print; }'
```

It `print`s when the line number `NR` is 2 and again on the final line.

**Note:** As pointed out in the comments, `$0` may or may not be available in an `END` block depending on your `awk` version.

Comment: @bishop - Yeah, not sure what I was thinking with that first one.  :P

Comment: @Mr.Llama This works well, is there a way I can assign certain arguments in ls to variables in awk?

Comment: Depending on how things are delimited, the `$`(number) variables are automatically set.  For example `$1` is the first field, `$2` is the second, etc.

Comment: @EdMorton - I wasn't aware of that.  Should I suggest `gawk` instead?

Answer (score 5):

Using the format stable GNU `stat` command:

```
stat --format='%s %n' * | sort -n | sed -n '1p;$p'
```

If you're using BSD `stat`, adjust accordingly.

If you want a lot more control over what files go into this calculation, and arguably better portability, use `find`. In this example, I'm getting all non-dot files in the current directory:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -not -path '*/\.*' -printf '%s %p\n' | sort -n | sed -n '1p;$p'
```

And take care if your directory contains two or fewer entries, or if any of your entries have a new-line in their name.

Comment: Just to be different, I went with `sed` instead of `awk`. :)

Comment: This call to `stat` would fail in the same instances that parsing the output of `ls` would: a filename that contains a newline character.

Comment: Also, the invocation to `stat` may vary; the above works with GNU `stat` but not BSD `stat`.

Comment: Dang it @chepner, you're spoiling my fun! ;P

Comment: I'd argue, btw, that nobody *plans* to have filenames with newlines, just like nobody plans to have strings that overflow their buffers when writing programs in C. The question is what you do with them when they happen. :)

Answer (score 1):

`ls` is not a reliable tool for this job: It can't represent all possible filenames (spaces are possible, but also newlines and other special characters -- all but NUL). One robust solution on a system with GNU tools is to use `find`:

```
{
    # read the first size and name
    IFS= read -r -d' ' first_size; IFS= read -r -d '' first_name;

    # handle case where only one file exists
    last_size=$first_size; last_name=$first_name

    # continue reading "last" size and name, until one really is last
    while IFS= read -r -d' ' curr_size && IFS= read -r -d '' curr_name; do
      last_size=$curr_size; last_name=$curr_name
    done
} < <(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%s %P\0' | sort -n -z)
```

The above puts results into variables `$first_size`, `$first_name`, `$last_size` and `$last_name`, usable thusly:

```
printf 'Smallest file is %d bytes, named %q\n' "$first_size" "$first_name"
printf 'Largest file is %d bytes, named %q\n' "$last_size" "$last_name"
```

---

In terms of how it works:

```
find ... -printf '%s %P\0'
```

...emits a stream of the following form from `find`:

```
<size> <name><NUL>
```

Running that stream through `sort -n -z` does a numeric sort on its contents. `IFS= read -r -d' ' first_size` reads the everything up to the first space; `IFS= read -r -d '' first_name` reads everything up to the first NUL; and then the loop continues to read and store additional size/name pairs until the last one is reached.

Answer (score 1):

```
whatever | awk 'NR==2{x=$0;next} {y=$0} END{if (x!="") print x; if (y!="") print y}'
```

You need that complexity (and more to be REALLY robust) to handle input that's less than 3 lines.